# Homomorphism theorems

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

When I listened lectures on rings or modules (it was 2 years ago) there were the homomorphism theorems.
Let $A$ be a ring, $M$ and $N$ are modules over A, $f: M\rightarrow N$ is a homomorpism , $M_1$ and $M_2$ are submodules of $M$. Also let $L\subset M \subset N$ be the triple of modules.
1) The first theorem states that $M/Ker(f)$ is isomorphic to $f(M)\subset N$.
2) The second states that $\frac{M_1+M_2}{M_1}$ is isomorphic to $\frac{M_2}{M_1\cap M_2}$.
3) The third states that $\frac{N/L}{M/L}$ is isomorphic to $N/M$.

I know some statements where the first theorem is extremely useful. Could you give me examples using the 2nd and the 3rd ones? I have never used it studying mathematics!

Answer (score 5):

They are all generalizations of the same facts in group theory. Every abelian group is a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, so any application of that to the theory of abelian groups should be an indication of how useful it is.

These theorems are everywhere in group theory. Some examples for abelian groups off the top of my head :

1. $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} \cong S^1$ because of the first isomorphism theorem applied to the homomorphism $x \mapsto e^{2\pi i x}$
2. If $n$ and $m$ are relatively prime, then the only homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/n \to \mathbb{Z}/m$ is the trivial one.
3. All quotients of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ are described by the third isomorphism theorem.

The list is quite literally endless. Just pick up a book on Abstract algebra and rifle through the section on the isomorphism theorems.

Comment: So, could you give expamples how useful in group theory the are?

Comment: @Prahlad: I've changed the $n$-adics to what they were supposed to be.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg : Thanks! To me, $\mathbb{Z}_n$ will always mean this, regardless of what you number theorists say :)